# Clearing HashMap straight after updateChildren breaks the functionality

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Calling:

```
HashMap<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
updates.put(myKey, null);
mDatabase.updateChildren(updates);
updates.clear();
```

Doesn't perform expected value removal from myKey location. It can be easily solved by cloning `updates` HashMap, calling:

```
mDatabase.updateChildren(new HashMap<String, Object>(updates));
```

Is this a bug or an expected behaviour? Is there documentation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update is sent to the Firebase Database asynchronously. You shouldn't modify the map you pass to Firebase until after the update has completed.

That's easy to do with the [`updateChildren()` method that takes a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#updateChildren)):

```
mDatabase.updateChildren(updates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
        if (error == null) {
            updates.clear();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll move it to the completion listener. Speaking of which, since its callback's argument is a DatabaseReference at the root of the database, does it mean it actually download the whole database after performing updateChildren? The documentation often advises to only fetch the smallest tree possible, hence having that root DatabaseReference makes me want to double check that a DataSnapshot is not being fetched along with it

Comment: A reference only downloads data once you attach a listener.